# Python desktop Cleaner - Access Deined

Tags: python

Recently I found a program that cleans your folders. This is the coding.

```
import os 
import shutil
lis=[]
destinationDir='C:\Users\Owner\All in two'
os.makedirs(destinationDir)
lis=os.listdir('C:\Users\Owner\My Documents')
for x in lis:
    if x==__file__:
        continue
    shutil.move(x,destinationDir)
```

When I try to run it though, it gives an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Cleaner.py", line 6, in <module>
    lis=os.listdir('C:\Users\Owner\My Documents')
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\My Documents/*.*'
```

I tried using cmd in admin but it failed.
All advice is appreciated.

Comment: sounds more like a windows/permissions issue than a python problem. You should use raw prefix for your windows paths for what it's worth BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the appropriate permissions on your computer!

Right click on the folder (My documents or a folder inside) and look in security, if you have all the permissions with a tick box in, then this error shouldn't occur!

Basically, if you're not admin or can't access my documents, then you can't run it!

Hope this helps XD